# How do I add a method with a decorator to a class in python?

Tags: python, decorator

How do I add a method with a decorator to a class?  I tried

```
def add_decorator( cls ):
    @dec
    def update(self):
        pass

    cls.update = update
```

usage

```
 add_decorator( MyClass )

 MyClass.update()
```

but MyClass.update does not have the decorator

@dec did not apply to update

I'm trying to use this with `orm.reconstructor` in sqlalchemy.

Comment: I fixed up your question to reflect what it seems like you were asking - but if I completely misinterpreted your intent, feel free to roll back the edit and clarify it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want class decorator in python >= 2.6 you can do this

```
def funkyDecorator(cls):
    cls.funky = 1

@funkyDecorator
class MyClass(object):
    pass
```

or in python 2.5

```
MyClass = funkyDecorator(MyClass)
```

But looks like you are interested in method decorator, for which you can do this

```
def logDecorator(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Before", func.__name__
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "After", func.__name__
        return ret

    return wrapper

class MyClass(object):

    @logDecorator
    def mymethod(self):
        print "xxx"


MyClass().mymethod()
```

Output:

```
Before mymethod
xxx
After mymethod
```

So in short you have to just put `@orm.reconstructor` before method definition

Answer (score 0):

In the class that represents your SQL record,

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import reconstructor

class Thing(object):
    @reconstructor
    def reconstruct(self):
        pass
```